# Azure Service Management API for .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, azure

I wanted to get the properties of the Role instances in a cloud service.

I am able to get the instance properties via REST Api call as mentioned [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460804.aspx)

This is the API I used,

> https://management.core.windows.net/subscription-id/services/hostedservices/cloudservice-name/deployments/deployment-name

But I am not able to find the .Net equivalent of that. I tried the following class,

> [RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn155810.aspx)

But it asks me for a connection string , deployment id and other stuffs which the REST API doesn't ask for. The REST API works well with cloudservice name and deployment name.How do I achieve this in .Net without giving connection string and other stuffs?

Is there any clear documentation to use Service Management API for .net with examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method

> public static DeploymentGetResponse GetByName(this
>   IDeploymentOperations operations, string serviceName, string
>   deploymentName);

under [DeploymentOperationsExtensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/WebSiteManagement/Generated/DeploymentOperationsExtensions.cs) helped in getting the role instance properties.

Comment: Isn't this for Azure Websites? I thought you want to know about Azure Cloud Services.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the library you would want to use is [`Azure Management Library`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries) which is a .Net wrapper over Service Management REST API. Check out this blog post from Brady which will get you started: http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries.

Comment: I followed the blog mentioned by you. If that API is a wrapper over REST API, why should it ask me for connection string,deployment id which I am not aware of in the programmatic environment?

Comment: the link is dead